# is there GUI framework for mobile and desktop applications?

Tags: user-interface, go

HI I'm big lover of golang but I'm beginner and I want to knew if it possible to build interface application with go for mobile or desktop 
I see video on YouTube that's talk about framework called GIO    https://gioui.org/     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxnL3-Sex3o
 but it's has small community and I've got many errors so is there any one familiar with GIO tell how to start if it's possible

Comment: Your question is [strictly off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please try [other venues](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community) to ask such question on Go, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the [Fyne](https://fyne.io) toolkit that aims to be easy to learn for anyone. It supports desktop and mobile and it's apps follow use material design using light and dark themes. There are tutorials available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-v1vz_NcWng&list=PLjpijTpXl1_po-ld8jORR9k5NornDNKQk) and there is a [tour](https://tour.fyne.io) if you prefer reading.